# Wrong nameservers show with `systemd-resolve --status`

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns, netplan, systemd-resolved

I have some rogue nameservers that I can't seem to get rid of on my ubuntu 20.04 server. I run 2 pihole instances, which have been configured to work with ipv4 and ipv6 Cloudflare DOH. When running `systemd-resolve --status` I see the following:

```
Global
       LLMNR setting: no                  
MulticastDNS setting: no                  
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                  
      DNSSEC setting: no                  
    DNSSEC supported: no                  
  Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.231       
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.231       
Fallback DNS Servers: 192.168.0.232

---

Link 5 (bond0)
      Current Scopes: DNS                                    
DefaultRoute setting: yes                                    
       LLMNR setting: yes                                    
MulticastDNS setting: no                                     
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                                     
      DNSSEC setting: no                                     
    DNSSEC supported: no                                     
  Current DNS Server: XXXX:XXXX:5201:85d2:dea6:32ff:fecd:c928
         DNS Servers: 192.168.0.232                          
                      192.168.0.231                          
                      XXXX:XXXX:5100:9ea7:dea6:32ff:fecd:c928
                      XXXX:XXXX:5100:9ea7:e267:f2a8:a283:a17e
                      XXXX:XXXX:5201:85d2:dea6:32ff:fecd:c928
                      XXXX:XXXX:5201:85d2:e138:3897:a08e:dc2a
```

The XXXX:XXXX:5201 addresses are the ones I'd like to remove.

My netplan is set up with a static bond

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  bonds:
    bond0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses: 
        - 192.168.0.178/24
      gateway4: 192.168.0.1
      nameservers:
        search: []
        addresses:
        - 192.168.0.232
        - 192.168.0.231
        - XXXX:XXXX:5100:9ea7:dea6:32ff:fecd:c928
        - XXXX:XXXX:5100:9ea7:e267:f2a8:a283:a17e
      interfaces:
      - enp6s0
      - enp7s0
      parameters:
        lacp-rate: slow
        mode: 802.3ad
        transmit-hash-policy: layer2
  ethernets:
    enp6s0: {}
    enp7s0: {}
  version: 2
```

That is the only yaml file in /etc/netplan/.

I've tried `sudo resolvectl revert bond0` and restarting the service but that didn't seem to have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One year later and I finally figured out my issue. DNS servers can be defined in the following locations.

```
/etc/netplan/*
/etc/systemd/network/*.network
/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/*
```

There may be more locations, but these are the ones I'm aware of. In my case, the extra DNS servers were in /etc/systemd/network/*.network.